# How to pass my object via RestTemplate

Tags: java, rest, uuid, resttemplate

I'm making simple REST service and the client for it. I try to make some kind of security, so I generate UUID just, when you go to /login site:

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public uuid getUUID()
{
    temp = new uuid();
    return temp;
}
```

Then by the client side I get this UUID. Now I want to pass this UUID to my service "getPerson" which looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/{userId}/getperson")
public Person getPerson(@PathVariable("userId") int user, uuid uuid)
{
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - uuid.getDate().getTime() < 60000 &&
            uuid.getHash().toString().equals(temp.toString()))
        return personService.getPerson(user);
    else
        return null;
}
```

What I wanted to achieve is a simple validation of UUID by comparing its timestamps and Strings with the previously made temp object. And here is my problem - I don't know how to pass the object uuid from client. 
My very sophisticated client looks like this:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
uuid myUUID = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/login", uuid.class);
HttpEntity<uuid> requestUUID = new HttpEntity<uuid>(myUUID);
//HttpEntity<Person> request = new HttpEntity<Person>(new Person("John", "Great", 2));

//restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/addperson", request, Person.class);
Person person = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/2/getperson", requestUUID, Person.class);
```

I don't know if this type of validation is safe, but would be great if you could tell me how to pass my object.

Comment: If a first user A comes  to login, you ll generate  an uuidA, and then a user  B tries  to login, so temp will be  equal to uuidB when B fetches the login page. so A will not be able to login even if he puts correct credentials... One solution is to store the temp in the session in your back-end. but it will violate the stateless philosophy of rest services..

Comment: Yes, it came to my mind. Couldn't I add field 'UUID' to where I store registered users? So making it very simple:
I make container for registered people, everyone has their ID and UUID. This UUID changes everytime the user logins. Then in validations I check UUID written in mentioned container and ID of the user. But is this states violation too?
Well, the case is I don't even know, how to pass this uuidA or uuidB from client to service.

Comment: Why do you need to pass  that uuid ?

Comment: I want to secure the usage of my services. I imagine using them like this: I log in via client -> I get UUID to my client if credentials are valid. The same time server knows this UUID (every UUID is unique for every user) -> now I want to use service, lets say, getPerson which is only for registered users. So my service firstly checks if the UUID from client is the same as the UUID saved in database. Also I see this UUID as something valid only for limited time before user must login again, like in banks' sites, so I check timestamps (which require some kind of refresh everytimeservice is run

Comment: I think there is way you can achieve your first need with spring security and crsf token. But i am sorry i m not an expert on it to help you  further...

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution below,

It is the concept which i shown below

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class Person {

private UUID uuid;

public Person() {
}

public Person(UUID uuid) {
    super();
    this.uuid = uuid;
}

public UUID getUuid() {
    return uuid;
}

public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person [uuid=" + uuid + "]";
}
}
```

Controller **IWebExample** Interface:

```
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

public interface IWebExample {

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
UUID getUUID();

@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}/getPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
Person getPerson(int userId, UUID uuid);
}
```

**Controller Implementation**

```
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

import com.finvendor.serverwebapi.resources.example.IWebExample;
import com.finvendor.serverwebapi.resources.example.Person;

@Controller
public class WebExampleImpl implements IWebExample {

@Override
public UUID getUUID() {
    return UUID.randomUUID();
}

@Override
public Person getPerson(@PathVariable("userId") int userId, @RequestBody UUID uuid) {
    return new Person(uuid);
}
}
```

**Client code:**

```
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class ClientMainApp {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    RestTemplate template=new RestTemplate();
    UUID uuid = template.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/mylogin",UUID.class);
    System.out.println("UUID="+uuid);

    //here i am passing uuid object (as per your requirement)
    Person person = template.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/1/getPerson", uuid, Person.class);
    System.out.println(person);
}
}
```

**Step to run**

-Create war file

-Deploy in tomcat and

-Run the client code

**Output would be:**

UUID=e1e89e96-8118-446c-900d-d123b1b566ea

Person [uuid=e1e89e96-8118-446c-900d-d123b1b566ea]

---

In output you can observe we pass object uuid in postForObject(...) rest template method in client code.

The bottom line of solution of your problem is you need to use  @RequestBody for uuid input param

Hope you got the idea and solution!!

Comment: Yes, exactly, @RequestBody annotation was the thing I needed! Thanks :)